# Changing projection changes area when calculated in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, terra

I have a raster with pixel values 1- area of interest and NA-not an area of interest and hence excluded completely. This raster has CRS WGS 1984, with no projection assigned to it and has resolution of 0.1 degrees.

I count the number of pixels with value 1 using

```
raster::cellStats(raster, sta="sum", na.rm=TRUE)
```

This gives me a value of 5911. Knowing that 0.1 degrees is approximately 11.1km, I can calculate the approximate area in million hectares to be

```
5911*11.1*11.1/10^4 # 10^4 conversion from sqkm to ha and then million ha
```

I then project this raster to WGS 1984 UTM 44N to a resolution of 100m, for further analyses, using nearest neighbor algorithm, as I am still interested in maintaining the 1 or NA pixel values. I do so

```
terra::project(rast(binary raster 1 or NA), raster of UTM 44N 100m, method="near", mask=TRUE)
```

I then calculate the area of the binary raster 1 or NA using the same cellStats() to check. I make the conversion from sqm to million ha and find that the area is 67.39 Mha.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: A tenth of a degree of longitude is only 11km at the Equator. Square Cartesian degrees are of no real use.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for your comment. So your point is that this is not a fair comparison and I should just go with the area after I project to 44N UTM? Also, making clear comments would be more useful.

Comment: You should only trust UTM 44N if the data is in UTM 44N. You haven't provided enough information to determine the correct calculation.

Comment: Would you want to specify additional info that I should provide?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `area` function to get a more accurate area of each cell in a raster. For a pole-to-pole raster, this ranges from:

```
> r=raster()
> range(area(r)[])
[1]   107.7756 12308.6191
```

If you sum `area(R)` for all your `R==1` pixels you should get a result that is more invariant to projection (but not completely because of other approximations).

Comment: And the `terra` equivalent to `raster::area` is `terra::cellSize`

Comment: Thank you very much Spacedman and @Robert Hijmans. One last question, what unit is the resulting area of a raster that has no projection i.e. has unit degrees, when using terra::cellSize() (raster::area() gives area in sqkm, correct?)?

Comment: From ?area: "Cell values represent the size of the cell in km2". Also: `sum(area(raster())[])` = 508,358,771 ; compare: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=surface+area+of+the+earth&ia=answer `terra::cellSize` lets you specify units and defaults to m^2: `sum(cellSize(rast())[])` is 5.100656e+14 (m^2)